# how do i get a gameobject to conform to other gameobject shapes

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject, rigid-bodies

Im trying to make a game in Unity and I want to have a gameObject fall and match the shape of the ground underneath it.

when the game is started:

[image: How the game starts]

what is does:

[image]

what I would like it to do

[image]

I'm pretty decent so even a hint in the right direction would be helpful.
thanks.

Comment: Try adding a mesh collider and modifying the mesh by code: https://answers.unity.com/questions/400406/bend-object-by-script.html

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to duplicate the ground object and replace the falling object with ta modified version of that duplicate. How you can do that is to do the following on entering a collision between the falling object and a given ground object:

1. Make sure this falling object hasn't already collided with this ground object, such as with a `fallingObject.lastCopiedGroundObject` `GameObject`.
2. Find the `y` of `groundObject`'s `Collider.bounds.size`
3. Add `y` to `groundObject.transform.position` to a new `Vector3 newPos`
4. Use `GameObject newFalling = Object.Instantiate(groundObject, newPos, groundObject.rotation, fallingObject.parent)`.
5. Copy `rotationalVelocity` and `velocity` from the fallingObject's rigidbody over to `newFalling`'s rigidbody, if appropriate.
6. Add, remove, modify components as necessary on `newFalling`, (such as replacing textures) to make it further behave and appear correctly as the falling object it is replacing.
7. Destroy the old falling object with `fallingObject.Destroy()`
8. Set the `lastCopiedGroundObject` of `newFalling` so that `newFalling` won't do this interaction with the same `groundObject` again, until another copy is done.

This will place the falling object above the ground object, and will let it fall using the physics engine to determine where it should rest on top.

One consideration is to instead use a `List<GameObject> alreadyCopiedGroundObjects` and to append the newly collided ground object to the list in the old falling object so that if the falling object touches multiple grounds, it will only change its shape to each one only once, so it won't perpetually oscillate between shapes in certain conditions.